# How to convert JSON object rows into JSON array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

Stuck in one exercise task where I want `JSON` objects to be in form of a `JSON` array. Actually I have reached up to 1st stage to convert things into `JSON` object first.

Second stage is where my output should be as same as expected output as below, but it is not coming.

Current output :

```
{"name": "Peter", "uniqueId": "1"}
{"name": "MaryChan", "uniqueId": "3"}
```

Expected output :

```
[{"name": "Peter", "uniqueId": "1"}, {"name": "MaryChan", "uniqueId": "3"}]
```

Query :

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('uniqueId', uniqueId, 'name', name) actors
FROM (
select stf.id as familyId, stl.skill_type_name  as name
from actor_family af, actor_layered al
where af.id = al.actor_family_id) AS actors
GROUP BY uniqueId;
```

Some have suggested to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get it done but still I'm not able to achieve the expected format.

Any help or pointers are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) aggregation function:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_AGG(JSON_OBJECT('uniqueId', uniqueId, 'name', name)) actors
FROM (
select stf.id as familyId, stl.skill_type_name  as name
from actor_family af, actor_layered al
where af.id = al.actor_family_id) AS actors
GROUP BY uniqueId;
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWGoTA5TnjeTSWJKohHYw1/0).

Comment: Man, that's simplest and elegant approach i have learned  today. Big thanks again for giving me helping hand.

Comment: Additional small tip: as long as this is an aggregation function, you can use a `GROUP BY` clause if you need to group specific rows that belong together on other columns. Glad this answer was helpful for you. @THINKINGMACHINE

Comment: Aye cap. Noted.